# Debugging Serverless Framework invoke local function

Tags: node.js, debugging, serverless-framework

I am trying to  debug sls invoke local.

My setup:[image]

However I keep getting:

```
/Users/nikos/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node --debug-brk=63417 --expose_debug_as=v8debug /Users/nikos/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/serverless invoke local -f createTodo
Debugger listening on [::]:63417

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

Answer (score 14):

OK, I've figured out how to do this with real Chrome Devtools with the excellent `node --inspect`. This is much better than node inspector because it uses the latest built in chrome devtools. [(more info on node inspect)](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)

`node --debug-brk --inspect $(which serverless) invoke local -f myfunctionname`

I ran that but my function wasn't loaded yet (probably some lazy loading in the serverless code). So I added a `debugger` to the top line of my function and everything seems to be working great.

In my case I also needed some test data, so I passed that through like this.

```
node --debug-brk --inspect $(which serverless) invoke local -f postprocess -d '{"Records":[{"eventVersion":"2.0","eventSource":"aws:s3","awsRegion":"us-east-1","eventTime":"2017-06-17T05:08:29.598Z","eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put","userIdentity":{"principalId":"ALS78N87ZDYNW"},"requestParameters":{"sourceIPAddress":"52.119.114.78"},"responseElements":{"x-amz-request-id":"2EB4FAD5892EC247","x-amz-id-2":"nVLasIYsWvWm7xwONiTB6z7L8oXKkvPOb9FntOYoG/kKS+PuWwbMJ1xM7n/C1X3NJh5FUCj4aEM="},"s3":{"s3SchemaVersion":"1.0","configurationId":"3c3b2a71-b639-4116-b246-08dcacd0c7d6","bucket":{"name":"simmer-uploads-test","ownerIdentity":{"principalId":"ALS78N87ZDYNW"},"arn":"arn:aws:s3:::simmer-uploads-test"},"object":{"key":"example+%285%29.zip","size":4757597,"eTag":"9aa90579ee4e8152e6dfa60258754a83","sequencer":"005944B94AD9307261"}}}]}'
```

I am working on a Mac, and I heard there might be some problems with $(which serverless) on windows. But someone give it a shot and let me know.

Comment: On windows I got this to work using `node --debug-brk --inspect %AppData%\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless invoke local -f functionName -p ./path/to/mock-event.json`

Comment: What should the function name be?

Comment: @Fluous The name of the function should be the name in your serverless.yml file, not the one in the code

Answer (score 8):

I was able to setup my *PHPStorm* debugger configuration in a way that now I can step through my functions locally (using *serverless-offline* plugin).

I am triggering functions via http requests using Postman.

See below steps to achieve this:

1.
[image: Setup configuration for debugging serverless app offline in PHPStorm]

2.
[image: Console output after debugger started]

3.
[image: Sending request via Postman]

4.
[image: Be able to step through your function]

Comment: Thanks! This work in IDEA Ultimate 2018 as well. One thing I noticed is that the Node.js config option doesn't show up if you click the toolbar run drop down, you have to configure this through the menu option Run > Edit Configurations...

Comment: Following this guide i get an Exception: basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @soulcinder Are you using Windows OS? What are you using for testing your project? I googled for your error and I guess it might be related to Windows OS plus some testing dependencies usage which might need to be tweaked. Please let me know your findings and give more details if needed.

Comment: yes i am using Windows OS.  i created a bug report for this issue in the serverless-offline repo: https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/581

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten this to work in IntelliJ, so it should work in Webstorm too. You will need the serverless-offline plugin (https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline)

In your Run Configuration, change your Application parameters to:

offline -s dev

and add the environment variable SLS_DEBUG=*

serverless-offline will start a server that the IntelliJ Node debugger can hook into.

Answer (score -1):

Use this, it emulates lambda and serverless:

https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline#debug-process